# UIPickerView isn't showing as inputview when UITextField begins to edit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have managed to add a UIPickerView as an input view to UITextField in viewDidLoad, but now I want to make the UITextField as first responder when another textfield (with tag =4) ends editing. This is the code I'm using:

This is in the viewdidload, and all the other code needed to initialize the picker view is there:

```
 UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    myPickerView.delegate = self;
    myPickerView.dataSource = self;
   myPickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:76/255.0 green:76/255.0 blue:76/255.0 alpha:1];
    textfieldInput.inputView = myPickerView;
```

This is in my text field did end editing method:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(textField.tag == 4){
        [textfieldInput becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```

The problem is that when the textfieldInput becomes the first responder, the picker view isn't shown, instead the keyboard is presented.
Also, it should be mentioned that i have another textfield on top of this that gets resigned if it became the first responder and becomes hidden. This textfield is the textfield that has a tag of 4. (This textfield has been added for design reasons).

Comment: You are attempting to make `textField` the first responder only when that same `textField` has just ended editing. That makes no sense.

Comment: No, the text field with the tag 4 is the one i've just ended editing. text field that will become the first responder is a new text field.

Comment: Ah. I didn't see the slight difference in variable names `textField` vs `textfield`. Never mind. That's some poor naming style. It's very prone to misreading and mistyping.

Comment: I have my variables named otherwise. I changed them here just to not have weird variable names.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me... are you sure that call the correct reference of textfield?

try: `[self.textfield becomeFirstResponder];`

Comment: No that didn't work. I am still getting the default keyboard.

Comment: What weird!, and do you debug this? are you sure that are calling to becomeFirstResponder after the edit the textfield

Comment: Yes, I added breakpoints and it's being called. Also, to prove that the text field is becoming first responder, the default keyboard is shown and I can type in values but the picker view isn't shown. Add to that that when I dismiss the keyboard and manually press it the picker view is then shown.

Comment: I have made an example and it works, you can download [here](https://github.com/DiegoQuimbo/PickerExample) and test it, basically it's the same code that you're using, are you testing with specific iOS?,